# Is there a way to host a Socket.Js server on Github?

Tags: javascript, github, socket.io, hosting

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});


server.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:8000');
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
io.emit('some event', { someProperty: 'some value', otherProperty: 'other value' }); // This will emit the event to all connected sockets
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

Currently it's localhost, and I have to run node index.js everytime I want to start it. But is there a way I can host it on GitHub so it always stays on?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

GitHub hosts git repositories containing code, but doesn't run code. GitHub pages can serve static sites, but cannot run server side code, which include node.js and express. If you want to host something like this for free, I suggest looking into [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).